# New Form opens focused, but in background

Tags: c#, winforms

I have following problem:

Double click in grid in my application causes opening of new form with detailed view of the data.

This new window should open on top of an application and be focused, but it is not child of the main window.

The problem is, that this works only sometimes.

i.e. two times the new window opens as top window and third time it only flashes and the main application stays on top (the focus is in the newly opened window, however.)

Here are snippets of my code:

```
 private void gridHistoryView_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GridView view = (GridView)sender;
            Point pt = view.GridControl.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition);
            DoRowDoubleClick(view, pt);
        }



private  void DoRowDoubleClick(GridView view, Point pt)
        {
            // some conditions to close the proccess

                LoadDetail(docType, docID);

            }
        }

private void LoadDetail(string docType, string docID)
        {
            Form frmHistoryDetail = new Form();
            frmHistoryDetail.TopLevel = true;
            frmHistoryDetail.TopMost = true;

            //retrieve data from database etc.


            frmHistoryDetail.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;


            frmHistoryDetail.Show();
}
```

Comment: *Not child* - do you mean modeless?

Comment: Did you try calling `frmHistoryDetail.BringToFront();` after the `Show()` call?

Comment: I tried that, but the behavior is still the same - the new window only flashes and then is put to back.

Comment: The snippet gives no hints.  Standard reasons for this happening is that the form is getting opened on a worker thread.  Or your app having no window that can receive the focus for a while so the OS is forced to find another window in another app to bring into the foreground.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about setting the owner of the new form to the main form?
This would still allow you to access the main form while the new form is visible.
The new form will then be on top of the main form, but NOT on top of other applications,
which normally is the desired behavior.

```
Form frmHistoryDetail = new Form();
frmHistoryDetail.Owner = this;

//retrieve data from database etc.

frmHistoryDetail.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;

frmHistoryDetail.Show();
```

Comment: That seems to solve the problem with top window, but unfortunately the behavior is not what I want - Now I can not just switch the focus to main window without minimizing the window.

Comment: I don't get that. I use that in more applications, where I have various floating windows on the main form. Here the users are switching back and forth the whole time.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting TopLevel and TopMost, you should be setting the parent of the dialog. This should be enough to ensure that it is shown above your desired window.

```
frmHistoryDetail.Show(this);
```

[MSDN Link for `Show(IWin32Window owner)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/szcefbbd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: This would not work, since I need to be able to switch to main application and seting parent of the form does not allow me to switch to parent form unless I am fineshed in the new one

Comment: @Zbynek - Maybe I've misunderstood your question.. you could always override the `LosingFocus` method, to set top most in that, but that doesn't seem very user friendly to me